# remove an updated text by using fabricjs canvas library

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

**Adding text Element**

```
function add_text() {   
    var myText = new fabric.Text(text,
    {
        fontSize: size,
        fontFamily: fm,
        strokeStyle: sc,
        fill: fc,
        left: myCanvas.getWidth()/2,
        top: myCanvas.getHeight()/2
    });

    myCanvas.add(myText);
}
```

**updating text and size**

```
function chng_txt() {
    var obj = myCanvas.getActiveObject();
    var fm = document.getElementById('up_text').value;
    obj.setText(fm);
    myCanvas.add(obj);
    myCanvas.renderALL();
}

function chng_fs() {
    var obj = myCanvas.getActiveObject();
    var fs = document.getElementById('up_size').value;
    obj.setFontsize(fs);
    myCanvas.add(obj);
    myCanvas.renderALL();
}
```

**Removing Text Element**

```
function rmv_txt() {
    var obj = myCanvas.getActiveObject();
    myCanvas.remove(obj);
}
```

**My Problem is**

that I could add text and update text.
But I can't remove text element which is updated.

Answer (score 1):

What actually happening is you were adding another object on the top of it, i.e there are two same object on the top of one another and when you were deleting it, it was deleting only the active object.

All you have to do is remove the line `myCanvas.add(obj);` when you're updating the text. so your code will looks like

```
function chng_fs() {
    var obj = myCanvas.getActiveObject();
    var fs = document.getElementById('up_size').value;
    obj.setFontsize(fs);
    myCanvas.renderAll();
}
```

Also one more things, it is always better to render the canvas when you make any changes, include the renderAll() after adding and deleting objects even though it works fine and its not "renderALL" it should be "renderAll", I think you know this, just a typo mistake while  posting otherwise you wont see the text property changed.